# How to preserve a UNIX datestamp with mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I would like to aggregate data in meteor/MongoDB. I have a few thousand entries formatted like the following

```
{_id: sadsadjhsjdys7ad67as8d, t: 1464162907, prod: 123, sys: xyz}
```

I would like to sort them into their relative dates and aggregate the prod field.

I currently have the following

```
var project = {
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "y" : {
            "$year" : {
                "$add" : [
                    new Date(0), {
                        "$multiply" : [1000, "$t"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "m" : {
            "$month" : {
                "$add" : [
                    new Date(0), {
                        "$multiply" : [1000, "$t"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "d" : {
            "$dayOfMonth" : {
                "$add" : [
                    new Date(0), {
                        "$multiply" : [1000, "$t"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        "prod" : "$prod",
        "sys" : "$sys"

    }
};
var group = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "year" : "$y",
            "month" : "$m",
            "day" : "$d",
            "test" : "$test"
        },
        sys : "sys",
        prod : {
            $sum : "$prod"
        }
    }
};

var result = power_stats.aggregate([match, project, group]);
```

However this makes my _id into [y: 2016, m: 5, d: 25] which is the form of aggregation that I want, however it will be completely useless if I want to do a conditional find with the date later on with this data.

How can I preserve a UNIX datestamp with MongoDBe aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that you can do:

1. Add `t` field in $project phase and keep populating it thru pipeline - so there will be always reference to oryginal timestamp
2. Create dateTime field 'time: new Date("$_id.year", "$_id.month", "_id.day");'

---

```
var group = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "year" : "$y",
            "month" : "$m",
            "day" : "$d",
            "test" : "$test"
        },

        prod : {
            $sum : "$prod"
        },
        dateTime : {
            $addToSet : new Date("$_id.year", "$_id.month", "$_id.day")
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So are you saying I use an update to make a time field? Only that I am trying to keep as much of this in mongodb as possible so I can handle bigger data

Comment: @AngusW having time field instead of epoch will speed-up all  operations (no need to convert)

Comment: Thankyou for helping me, I am just learning these more advanced mongo systems now and am unable to get a working new field. Just double checking that the new field would be in the $group correct? Could you possibly show me exactly where it would go>

Comment: @AngusW just added modified group statement, btw `sys` field need to be pushed to array as it cannot stand on its own in group pipeline